# Constructor treenode in class treenode cannot be applied to given types in java?

Tags: java, debugging, treenode

```
    /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public TreeNode buildTree(int[] preorder, int[] inorder) {
        TreeNode ans = new TreeNode();
        if(preorder.length == 0) return ans;
        // do something
        return ans;
    }
```

I want to initialize a empty `TreeNode`, but meet the error as follow:

```
constructor treenode in class treenode cannot be applied to given types
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define default constructor explicitly when you define a constructor with arguments.

```
TreeNode() { 
    //initialize value 
}
```